# What windows account is Railo running under

Tags: railo, cfml

How do I find what windows user account Railo is running under on windows 2008 r2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can use the `System` properties, same as in ACF:

```
<cfscript>
    prop = createObject("java", "java.lang.System").getProperties();
    WriteDump( var=prop["user.name"], label="User.Name");
    WriteDump( var=prop, label="All Properties" );
</cfscript>
```